# Etiquette for accepting more detailed own answer based on original answer

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer, self-answer, ethics

A few days back I asked a question

[How to autowire default XmlMapper in Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812065/how-to-autowire-default-xmlmapper-in-spring-boot-application)

explaining what I was doing and what I was expecting to happen, and that it wasn't working, and the final question was "Any idea why this is?".

I quickly got a succinct answer explaining precisely what I asked.

This helped me a lot, I accepted and upvoted the answer.

Based on this information I did some more digging and found a way to do what I wanted to do in a slightly different way.

I left a comment on the answer explaining what I found and that it worked for me.

I feel that this might be useful for other people having the same issue, but the information isn't very visible in the comment.

I could post another answer myself and put the information in there, but should I accept my own answer instead? My own answer would be more helpful to solve my issue, but I don't want to penalize the original answer, since I would have never found out how to do what I want to do without it, and in the original question I only asked "why is this?" and not "how can I do this in another way?"

What is the etiquette in this case?

Comment: Do whatever you want.  You're free to accept whatever answer you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth, I've been in a similar situation. I posted this question:

[How do I make a WPF window movable by dragging the extended window frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493149/how-do-i-make-a-wpf-window-movable-by-dragging-the-extended-window-frame)

with the intention of finding a solution to the problem. I don't think it's a broad question, but I recognized that potential solutions would be non-trivial and so I was content with accepting an answer that at least pointed me in the right direction. I accepted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493149/how-do-i-make-a-wpf-window-movable-by-dragging-the-extended-window-frame/5493446#5493446) for doing just that, and in my own time I came up with an answer of my own detailing a complete solution.

This is where choosing a different answer to accept is entirely personal preference; personally I chose to pass the check to my own answer for the reason that it provided a complete solution to the problem. Like you, I was concerned that by unaccepting I would be penalizing the original answer, so I awarded a nice big bounty as a way of saying thanks for pointing me to what would eventually be my solution.

Comment: That probably had the added effects of 1. Making sure your answer was listed first due to upvotes (accept does not help self-answers there) 2. Giving you more rep back than you invested by not accepting someone elses answer and giving out a bounty together (not that rep at your level is any consideration, especially as you are a mod).

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yeah, I kinda wish more people upvoted the other answer too. But it's clear that people favor a complete solution over a hint - it's just "unfortunate" (if you could even say that!) that I was the one to provide said solution (because God forbid I solve my own problems, right? :P).